# If $a^n=a$ for a fixed positive even integer $n$, for all $a\in R$, show that $a=-a$ and that $a+b=0\implies a=b \forall a,b\in R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Suppose that there is a positive even integer $n$ such that $a^n = a$ for all the elements $a$ of some ring $R$. Show that $a+a=0$ for all $a \in R$ and $a+b = 0 \implies a=b$ for all  $a, b \in R.$

I could prove it only for $n=2$. But how to prove it for any even number in general?

Comment: $a^n=a$,  $(-a)^n=-a$

Comment: @i707107 can you please explain...thanks

Comment: Dear Sheetal, If you know that $a+a = 0$, and also $a + b = 0$, then adding $a$ to both sides gives $b = a$.  Regards,

Answer (score 5):

You can prove it by induction starting with $n=2$.

Or you can prove it this way. Remember that the goal is to prove that
$a=-a$.

Since $a^{n}=a$ and $n$ is even, then $\left(-1\right)^{n}=1$,
where $1$ is the identity in $R$. So
\begin{eqnarray*}
a & = & a^{n}\\
 & = & \left(-1\right)^{n}a^{n}\\
 & = & \left(-a\right)^{n}\\
 & = & -a.
\end{eqnarray*}
The next part is fairly similar.
\begin{eqnarray*}
a+b & = & 0\\
a & = & -b\\
a^{n} & = & b^{n}\\
a & = & b.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Answer by [@vantonio1992](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/456965) is not appropriate as we can solve the problem without assuming unity.

For first part: $(a+a)^2=a+a\Rightarrow a(a+a)+a(a+a)=(a^2+a^2)+(a^2+a^2)=(a+a)+(a+a)=(a+a)\Rightarrow a+a=0$.
Second part of your question can be answered the way [@Matt E](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456937/if-an-a-for-a-fixed-positive-even-integer-n-for-all-a-in-r-show-that-a#comment983368_456937) described.